# jquery не видит идентификатор в разметке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Использую Material Bootstrap Design. Появилась небольшая проблема во время использования js-скрипта.
HTML:

```
<div class="ml-auto text-right mt-5">
     <button id="btnClear" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ">Очистить</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnFirst').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#collapseFirstStep').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseTwoStep').collapse('show');
});

$('#btnTwo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#collapseTwoStep').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseThreeStep').collapse('show');
});

$('#btnClear').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#collapseThreeStep').collapse('hide');
    $('#collapseFirstStep').collapse('show');
});

});
```

С таким кодом, скрипт не может увидеть элемент с идентификатором "btnClear", но если изменить на "btn1", например, то заработает. Не могли бы подсказать почему так происходит?

UPD Заливаю картинку, чтобы не было вопросов про еще один идентификатор в html:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у вас там случайно нигде нету 2го `btnClear` ?

Comment: Вангую русскую букву С

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Нет. Я пробовал выводить элемент через console.log('#btnClear'), но вообще ничего не выводило.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не-а, только что проверил :D

Comment: Берём консоль и пишем руками. Чо тут советовать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через консоль создать элемент и по нему прогнать Ваш скрипт. Скорее всего, консоль укажет, где ошибка.
Возможно, вы вставили скрипт в `.

> К слову: если скрипт сидит в начале и у него нет атрибута `defer`, то он подгружается первым и не видит элементов.

Comment: Скрипт в document ready